# Got Exception Error “Exception in thread Thread-13 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)”

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

I wrote a simple script, which using threads to retrieve data from service.

```
    __author__ = 'Igor'
import requests
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

ip_list = []
good_ip_list = []
bad_ip_list = []
progress = 0

with open('/tmp/ip.txt') as f:
    ip_list = f.read().split()

def process_request(ip):
    global progress
    progress += 1
    if progress % 10000 == 0:
        print 'Processed ip:', progress, '...'
    r = requests.get('http://*****/?ip='+ip, timeout=None)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        good_ip_list.append(ip)
    elif r.status_code == 400:
        bad_ip_list.append(ip)
    else:
        print 'Unknown http code received, aborting'
        exit(1)

pool = ThreadPool(16)
try:
    pool.map(process_request, ip_list)
except:
    for name, ip_list in (('/tmp/out_good.txt', good_ip_list),     ('/tmp/out_bad.txt', bad_ip_list)):
        with open(name, 'w') as f:
            for ip in ip_list:
                print>>f, ip
```

But after some requests processed (40k-50k) i receive:

Exception in thread Thread-7 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Process finished with exit code 0

Tried to change service settings:

```
        <timeout>999</timeout>
        <connectionlimit>600</connectionlimit>
        <httpthreads>32</httpthreads>
        <workerthreads>128</workerthreads>
```

but still same error. Can anybody help me - what's wrong?

Comment: ` print>>f, ip` is this a typo? Is there anything else in the traceback?

Comment: `progress += 1` in language with mutable data and using multiple threads w/o any protection...  I stopped looking at that point ;)

Comment: @PatrickCollins as i understood - the problem in requests.exceptions.ConnectionError raise, tried to catch it and continue pool.map but same effect

Comment: @iced do not look at this block:
    global progress
    progress += 1
    if progress % 10000 == 0:
        print 'Processed ip:', progress, '...'
it's just for showing progress.

Comment: Also, i'm newby to Python, so if you are able to explain me my mistakes, i would improve my skills and would be thankful.

Comment: your code is wrong. same with good/bad_ip_list.append (shared lists accessed from multiple threads w/o any protection). you need to learn how to make multithreaded apps in python first. I can bet that is the reason for error you are getting, but I'm not going to investigate it deeper while it's bad from very start.

Comment: simple explanation - when 2 threads are trying to append to the same list in the same time bad things will happen. I have no idea why they advocate languages with mutable data as good for beginners...

Comment: @iced thanks for explanations. I read about multithreading here:
http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72914/discussion-between-iced-and-igor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to everybody, who helped me in solving this problem. Rewrote the whole code and now it works perfectly:

```
__author__ = 'kulakov'
import requests
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

ip_list = []
good_ip_list = []
bad_ip_list = []

with open('/tmp/ip.txt') as f:
    ip_list = f.read().split()

s = requests.Session()
def process_request(ip):
    r = s.get('http://*****/?ip='+ip, timeout=None)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # good_ip_list.append(ip)
        return (ip, True)
    elif r.status_code == 400:
        # bad_ip_list.append(ip)
        return (ip, False)
    else:
        print 'Unknown http code received, aborting'
        exit(1)

pool = ThreadPool(16)
for ip, isOk in pool.imap(process_request, ip_list):
    if isOk:
        good_ip_list.append(ip)
    else:
        bad_ip_list.append(ip)
pool.close()
pool.join()

for name, ip_list in (('/tmp/out_good.txt', good_ip_list),    ('/tmp/out_bad.txt', bad_ip_list)):
    with open(name, 'w') as f:
        for ip in ip_list:
            print>>f, ip
```

Some new usefull information:

1) It was really bad idea to write data in different threads in a function `process_request`, now it returns statement(true\false) and ip.

2) `keep alive` is fully supported by `requests`, by default, but if you want to use it, you must create instance of an object `Session`, and apply `get` method to it only:

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('http://*****/?ip='+ip, timeout=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
good_ip_list = []
bad_ip_list = []
```

is not safe to mix with Python multiprocessing. The correct approach is to return a tuple (or something) from each call to `process_request` and then concatenate them all at the end. It's also not safe to modify `progress` concurrently from multiple processes. I'm not positive what your error is, but I bet it's some synchronization problem that is killing Python as a whole.

Remove the shared state and try again.

Comment: Thanks, @Patrick Collins

I guess you're right with this suggestion:
"I bet it's some synchronization problem that is killing Python as a whole"

Can you explain little bit more, please this point:
"Remove the shared state and try again."

As input data i have a function 'process_request' and a list 'ip_list'.
So what's the right way to map this 2 objects not in cycle (as i tried with cycle it worked perfectly, but very slow) but in different threads.
Thank you.

Comment: @Igor take out the references to `good_ip_list, bad_ip_list` and `progress` inside `process_request`. Don't modify anything inside `process_request` except objects you've created inside `process_request`. Instead, do something like returning `true` or `false` in the call depending on whether the IP was good or not.